# Ruby on Rails - old version deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to deploy a ruby on rails version 1.x application on a ubuntu server with Apache and Phusion passenger. Since it's a very old version I don't find any documentation and guides.

Also, wondering about setting it up locally as there's no Gemfile.